# Reverse mapping using array from

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a set of `Map` data which I need to use both ways; here is an example:

```
const mapping: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>([
    ['one', '1'],
    ['two', '2'],
    ['three', '3'],
    ['four', '4'],
]);

// I should eliminate this; I want to write it with single-line syntax
const reverseMapping: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>([
    ['1', 'one'],
    ['2', 'two'],
    ['3', 'three'],
    ['4', 'four'],
]);

const data = Array.from(mapping).map(e => e.reverse());

const reverseMap: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>([data])
```

I can't figure out syntax-wise how to do this; how would I do this?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-d7jocb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A one-liner that works at both runtime and with the compiler is this:

```
const flipMap = <K, V>(m: Map<K, V>) => new Map(Array.from(m, ([k, v]) => [v, k]));
// const flipMap: <K, V>(m: Map<K, V>) => Map<V, K>
```

For your particular map you could do this:

```
const reverseMapping = new Map(Array.from(mapping, ([k, v]) => [v, k])); 
// const reverseMapping: Map<string, string>
```

Let's test it:

```
console.log(mapping); // Map(4) { one → "1", two → "2", three → "3", four → "4" }
console.log(reverseMapping); // { 1 → "one", 2 → "two", 3 → "three", 4 → "four" }
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA5IJZgOYC4YFlkA80ATuhgDQwlkB8MAvDGAKYDueh1mlXGNAFAG0AUDDExBAcnDNJlSQEZJAXXKjxUqKxByYkgEwq14iZKgALYs1nyAzEZjqxUgGYgArsV2SALEeHKAJQA3MLCoJCwLgA2qEj4SAwwBADSlABqAnA4CakZNIEMdCzsCfwAgsTECACeAHQuxCBw-HCUQgDWlABuQUUS3ZQdQSHCAPRjMBHQMDFxCTh5MJmtOYRpywX9uemUKTRh07BW3czEEMwJaJhJJRxIFVW1DU0tiChk7YJdML2F9HRBIMYMNAiEYBN7kQoKRuFQYbRDuAICBosw6tEQBhWshrhhwZCyj5CgBvGAyGCAJMIYAAiBQ0yhaEBU2n6BkwCxWZgsmm2dluTw8nw0mAAX3CyNR6Mx2JOZwuVzIBMmZIUPJk7P0PKZ7Ns2ss1nZPh5AuIIvFwiAA)

Comment: Additionally, you don't need to use the `.map()` method. The second parameter of `Array.from()` handles mapping. Therefore you can shorten it to: `new Map(Array.from(mapping, ([k, v]) => [v, k]));`